# Hoeffding's Lemma: verification of a result

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm having trouble to understand the following result.

Let $F$ be the joint distribution function and $F_X,F_Y$ the marginal distribution function of the random variables $X,Y$ respectively. Let $(X,Y), (X_2,Y_2)$ be independent and distributed according to $F$. Assume $E\mid XY\mid, E\mid X \mid, E\mid Y \mid$ finite. Then

\begin{equation}
2Cov(X,Y)=E((X-X_2)(Y-Y_2))
\end{equation}

**My attempt**

$2Cov(X,Y)=Cov(X_2,Y_2)+Cov(X,Y)$ since $(X_2,Y_2)$ and $(X,Y)$ are identically distributed. Now I need: (i) $E(Y_2)=E(Y)$;and (ii) the independence of $X_2\perp Y$ and $X\perp Y_2$ , because then 
\begin{align}
Cov(X_2,Y_2)+Cov(X,Y)&=
E(X_2Y_2)+E(XY)-E(X_2)E(Y_2)-E(X)E(Y)\\
&=E(X_2Y_2+XY)-E(X_2)E(Y)-E(X)E(Y_2)\\
&=E(X_2Y_2+XY-X_2Y-XY_2)\\
&=E((X-X_2)(Y-Y_2)).
\end{align}
Indeed, the probability distribution $P_{XY}$ is uniquely determined by the (cumulative) distribution function $F$. So $F_Y(y)=P_{XY}( \mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,y])=P_{X_2Y_2}( \mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,y])=F_{Y_2}(y)$, which in turn, implies that the marginal probability distribution of $Y$ and $Y_2$ are the same, i.e., $P_{Y}=P_{Y_2}$. Hence $E(Y)=\int x P_Y(dx)=\int x P_{Y_2}(dx)=E(Y_2)$. To see the independence,
$$F_{X,Y_2}(x,y_2)=\lim_{y,x_2\rightarrow \infty}F_{X,Y,X_2,Y_2}(x,y,x_2,y_2)=\lim_{x_2\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_2,Y_2}(x_2,y_2) \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)=F_X(x)F_{Y_2}(y_2)$$.

Can you give me a feedback of this attempt?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks good to me.