# Hoeffding's lemma: hard to prove

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

This is a continuation of another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361403/hoeffdings-lemma-verification-of-a-result).

Let $F$ be the joint distribution function and $F_X,F_Y$ the marginal distribution function of the random variables $X,Y$ respectively. Let $(X,Y), (X_2,Y_2)$ be independent and distributed according to $F$. Assume $E\mid XY\mid, E\mid X \mid, E\mid Y \mid$ finite. Then

\begin{align}
&E\bigg\{\int\int\Big[I(X\leq x)-I(X_2\leq x)\Big]\Big[I(Y\leq y)-I(Y_2\leq y)\Big]dxdy\bigg\}\\
&=2\int\int F_{X,Y}(x,y)-F_X(x)F_Y(y)dxdy
\end{align}
where $I$ is the indicator function.

**My attempt**

There are two challenging steps for me.

Firstly, I think I have to show that I can put the expectation inside the integrals using Fubini-Tonelli's theorem. Unfortunately I'm struggling to deal with it. Well, I know that the integrand is a (measurable) function of the random variables $X,Y,X_2$ and $Y_2$. So I saw the $L.H.S.$ of the above equality as

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}\int\int\Big[I(x_1\leq x)-I(x_2\leq x)\Big]\Big[I(y_1\leq y)-I(y_2\leq y)\Big]dxdy P_{X,Y,X_2,Y_2}(dx_1dy_1dx_2dy_2)$$
I don't know if this allows me to interchange the integrals to obtain
\begin{align}
&\int\int\ E\bigg\{\Big[I(X\leq x)-I(X_2\leq x)\Big]\Big[I(Y\leq y)-I(Y_2\leq y)\Big]\bigg\}dxdy\\
\end{align}
If everything is alright so far, then I need to show that  $E\bigg\{\Big[I(X\leq x)-I(X_2\leq x)\Big]\Big[I(Y\leq y)-I(Y_2\leq y)\Big]\bigg\}=2Cov(I(X\leq x),I(Y\leq y))$, and the rest becomes straighforward to me. Thus I need to show (i) the independence of $I(X_2\leq x)\perp I(Y\leq y)$ and $I(X\leq x)\perp I(Y_2\leq y)$ given $X_2\perp Y$ and $X\perp Y_2$; and (ii) $E(I(Y\leq y))=E(I(Y_2\leq y))$ which is easy, and that $Cov(I(X\leq x),I(Y\leq y))=Cov(I(X_2\leq x),I(Y_2\leq y))$.

I wonder if you can help me with it.

**UPDATE**
Since $X$ is independent of $Y_2$, by definition, $\sigma(X)=\{X^{-1}(B):B\in \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\sigma(Y_2)$ are independent, meaning that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B), \ \forall A\in \sigma(Y_2), B\in \sigma(X)$. Since $f=I_{(-\infty,x]}$ and $g=I_{(-\infty,y]}$ are $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})-(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})$measurable functions, then $(f\circ X)^{-1}=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(A))\in \sigma(X), \forall A\in \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$. The same holds for $g\circ Y_2$. It implies $\sigma(f\circ X)\subseteq \sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(g\circ Y_2)\subseteq \sigma(Y_2)$. Hence $\sigma(f\circ X)$ and $\sigma(g\circ Y_2)$ are also independent. That is the indicator functions (measurable) preserve the independence of the random variables.

Exploring one of the answers below, let $f,b:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ measurable functions (like the indicator functions I am interested in). Then $F_{f\circ X, g\circ Y}(x_1,y_1)=P\{f(X)\leq x_1, g(Y)\leq y_1\}=P(X\in f^{-1}(-\infty,x_1], Y\in g^{-1}(-\infty,y_1])=P_{XY}(f^{-1}(-\infty,x_1]\times g^{-1}(-\infty,y_1])=P_{X_2Y_2}(f^{-1}(-\infty,x_1]\times g^{-1}(-\infty,y_1])=F_{f\circ X_2, g\circ Y_2}(x_1,y_1)$. This immediately implies $Cov(f\circ X_2, g\circ Y_2)=Cov(f\circ X, g\circ Y)$. Just put $f=I_{(-\infty,x]}$ and $g=I_{(-\infty,y]}$. Finally, it is clear that the marginal probability distributions must be the same ($P_X=P_{X_2}$), by assumption. Therefore, $E(f\circ X)=\int_{\Omega} (f\circ X)(z) P(dz)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(w) P_X(dw)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(w) P_{X_2}(dw)=E(f\circ X_2)$, since $f$ is nonnegative measurable function (the indicator function)[see the Corollary 5.5.1, Resnick, A probability path, p. 138].

Answer (score 3):

Exchange of order of integration will be an application of Fubini's theorem applied to $g(x,y,\omega)=\Big(\mathbb{1}(X(\omega)\leq x)-\mathbb{1}(X_2(\omega)\leq x)\big)\big(\mathbb{1}(Y(\omega)\leq y)-\mathbb{1}(Y_2(\omega)\leq y)\Big)$. This is $dP\otimes dx\otimes dy$ integrable; in fact,
$$\int_\Omega\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} |g(x,y,\omega)|dx \,dy\,P(d\omega)= E\big[|X-X_2||Y-Y_2|\big]\leq 2(E[|XY|]+E[|X|]E[|Y|])<\infty$$
by independence and the integrability assumptions.

Comment: I didnt undestand your $g$ function

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood your argument. I was confused because it seems to mix Lebesgue integral and improper Riemann integral. How should I face this $dx dy dP$? Actually, it always bothered me, but never found a solution to understand that.

Comment: Taking expectation is the same as integrating over the probability measure P. I am thinking in terms of Lebesgue integration.

Comment: But to use Fubini's theorem, isn't it necessary that all three integrals be lebesgue integral? I mean, what is the measure in $dx dy$?

Comment: Abstract Lebesgue integration deals with measure on measurable spaces, not only the real line. If all this confuses you, increase the number of integrals and assume that there are joint densities with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the plane.

Answer (score 2):

i) Independence of $(X,Y)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ implies independence of $X$ and $Y_2$. This implies independence of $f(X)$ and $g(Y_2)$ for any measurable functions $f,g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Hence it implies independence of $I_{X_2 \leq x}$ and $I_{Y\leq y}$. Similarly we get independence of $I_{X \leq x}$ and $I_{Y_2\leq y}$.

ii) Since $(X,Y)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ have the same distribution it follows that $(f(X),g(Y))$ and $(h(X_2),k(Y_2))$ have the same distribution for any measurable functions $f,g,h,k:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. The equality of covariances follows from this immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give me directions to show your second result? That holds even if $f\neq h$ and $g\neq k$?